# When a capacitor finishes charging

Tags: charge, capacitance

When a capacitor is fully charged I usually hear the phrase "the potential difference across the capacitor opposes the battery potential difference, so no more charge flows". What does "the potential difference across the capacitor opposes the battery potential difference" mean?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A capacitor stores electric energy in a static electric field between two conductors. The conductors are separated by an insulator called a dielectric, which allows the conductors to be very close to each other without contact.  The closer together the conductors, the greater the storage capacity of the capacitor.  This storage capacity also is proportional to the voltage applied to the capacitor.

When the capacitor is connected across the terminals of a battery, the electromotive force of the battery (voltage) pushes electric charge from the capacitor's negative side to its positive side.  As charge migrates to the positive side, electrons migrate to the negative side, and an electric field is created between the two conductors.  Energy is stored in the capacitor's static electric field between the two conductors.

This is like when you walk up a flight of stairs.  You store potential energy at the top of the stairs, and if you slide down the bannister, you release the potential energy.  Likewise, when the capacitor discharges, it releases its potential in the form of current flowing across the static electric field.

When you've reached the top of the stairs, you may continue to move your legs, but you'll go no higher.  You've reached the limit of the energy storage potential of that particular staircase.  The potential difference of the staircase is the amount of motive power applied to drive you from the bottom of the staircase to the top, and it equals the amount of motive power released when you slide down the bannister.

A capacitor is like a battery, and a battery is like a capacitor, except that a battery generally has much greater storage capacity than a capacitor, and it discharges its energy more slowly.  The energy released by the battery is driven into the capacitor by the potential difference across the battery's terminals.  When the capacitor has reached its storage potential for whatever voltage is being used, its potential difference equals the potential difference across the battery's terminals, and that particular potential difference will drive no more charge into the capacitor.

Comment: This is extremely clear, thank you very much! I have a question: Why does current flow across the static electric field when it discharges ("when the capacitor discharges, it releases its potential in the form of current flowing across the static electric field")? I thought current can't flow across the plates of a capacitor because they are insulated from each other?

Comment: If the battery is disconnected, the potential difference of the capacitor drives charge, just as the potential difference of the battery drove charge into the capacitor.  The plates of a battery are insulated from each other, just like the plates of a capacitor.  The purpose of the insulator is to create space between the plates where a static electric field may form.  Here is a clearer and more complete explanation of what happens in a capacitor: http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_1/chpt_13/1.html